# Template definition in Makefile with dynamic variables from a loop

Tags: variables, dynamic, makefile

Can you somehow replace variables defined with Makefile `define` inside loops?

```
VERSION ?= v1.0.0
CPUARCHS := amd64 arm arm64
DESCRIPTION := This is epic application doing epic things

# Manifest format for X
export define TEMPLATE_FORMAT1
Version: $(VERSION)
Arch: $$$$arch

$(DESCRIPTION)
endef

# Some other manifest format for Y
export define TEMPLATE_FORMAT2
pkgver=$(VERSION)
cpuarch=$$$$arch
descr=$(DESCRIPTION)
endef


format1:
        @for arch in $(CPUARCHS); do \
          echo "$$TEMPLATE_FORMAT1"; \
        done

format2:
        @for arch in $(CPUARCHS); do \
          echo "$$TEMPLATE_FORMAT2"; \
        done

genformats: format1 format2
        @echo Done.
```

This results in:

```
% make format1   
Version: v1.0.0
Arch: $$arch

This is epic application doing epic things
Version: v1.0.0
Arch: $$arch

This is epic application doing epic things
Version: v1.0.0
Arch: $$arch

This is epic application doing epic things
```

Can you replace the `$$arch` with the one used in the loop? Of course there will be a lot more variables in real world situation than just simple `$$arch` so is there "hassle-free" solution (ie. no bazillion `sed`'s or other commands for each different template format target)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first, in bash when you do `a=$b b=c echo $a`, it will output `$b` rather than `c` -- it does not expand the variable within the variable.

In your case you are doing `echo "$$TEMPLATE_FORMAT1"` which will be translated to `echo "$TEMPLATE_FORMAT1"` by make, and then passed to bash, at which point `$TEMPLATE_FORMAT1` will contain `$$arch`, which is not expanded any further.

If your makefile tried to do `echo $$arch`, however, it would expand to `echo $arch`, and bash would expand the value of `$arch` at that point.   So you could try to use `$$arch` in `$(TEMPLATE_FORMAT1)` directly.

The trick is your define has newlines in it, and if you try to expand `echo $(TEMPLATE_FORMAT1)`, this would result in something like`echo line1` (newline) `line2` (newline) `line3`, (so the echo only applies to the first).   To get around this, you could substitute the newlines to `\n`'s, and the echo with a `-e`:

```
VERSION ?= v1.0.0
CPUARCHS := amd64 arm arm64
DESCRIPTION := This is epic application doing epic things

# Manifest format for X
export define TEMPLATE_FORMAT1
Version: $(VERSION)
Arch: $$arch
$(DESCRIPTION)
endef

define newline


endef


format1:
        @echo $@
        @for arch in $(CPUARCHS); do \
          echo -e "$(subst $(newline),\n,$(TEMPLATE_FORMAT1))"; \
        done

genformats: format1 format2
        @echo Done.
```

outputs

```
Version: v1.0.0
Arch: amd64
This is epic application doing epic things
Version: v1.0.0
Arch: arm
This is epic application doing epic things
Version: v1.0.0
Arch: arm64
This is epic application doing epic things
```